# syntax error, unexpected keyword_end after launching Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, sidekiq

My application uses `Sidekiq` and `Sidekiq-Cron` for background job processing. 
Both Sidekiq and Sidekiq-Cron are included as gems in the global section of my Gemfile, and installed with `bundle install` in my application's rvm gemset.

After launching for the first time `sidekiq` or `bundle exec sidekiq` from the root of my Rails application, I received the following error message which I past and copy here for completeness:

```
asarluhi@home:~/workspace/fantasytennis_app (background-jobs)*$ sidekiq
2017-01-16T09:04:36.460Z 3850 TID-7pc7o INFO: Booting Sidekiq 4.2.7 with redis options {:url=>nil}
/home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:477:in `load': /home/asarluhi/workspace/fantasytennis_app/app/workers/check_collections_worker.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:477:in `block in load_file'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:662:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `load_file'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:375:in `block in require_or_load'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:117:in `exclusive'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:511:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `const_get'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `block in constantize'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `each'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `inject'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `constantize'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/sidekiq-cron-0.4.5/lib/sidekiq/cron/job.rb:304:in `initialize'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/sidekiq-cron-0.4.5/lib/sidekiq/cron/job.rb:186:in `new'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/sidekiq-cron-0.4.5/lib/sidekiq/cron/job.rb:186:in `block in load_from_array'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/sidekiq-cron-0.4.5/lib/sidekiq/cron/job.rb:185:in `each'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/sidekiq-cron-0.4.5/lib/sidekiq/cron/job.rb:185:in `load_from_array'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/sidekiq-cron-0.4.5/lib/sidekiq/cron/job.rb:156:in `load_from_hash'
    from /home/asarluhi/workspace/fantasytennis_app/config/initializers/sidekiq.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq.rb:73:in `configure_server'
    from /home/asarluhi/workspace/fantasytennis_app/config/initializers/sidekiq.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /home/asarluhi/workspace/fantasytennis_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:244:in `require'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:244:in `boot_system'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:50:in `run'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/bin/sidekiq:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/asarluhi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@fantasytennis_app_Rails5.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I checked my `app/workers/check_collections_worker.rb` file, which raises the "unexpected keyword_end" syntax error in line 3 of the above code, but there are no errors, as you can see:

```
Class CheckCollectionsWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform
        collections = TennisCollection.all
        collections.each do |collection|
            collection.update_attribute(:check, false)
        end
    end
end
```

Sidekiq loads its jobs from top to bottom of a list contained in `config/schedule.yml`. The `CheckCollectionsWorker` class, being at the top, is loaded first. 
I tried to move to the top in turn each of the jobs inside `config/schedule.yml`, but for any of them I keep receiving the same "unexpected keyword_end" error message.
I am sure my code is correct. The "unexpected keyword_end" reported by sderr should be where (and as) it is.

Below is an extract of `config/schedule.yml` concerning the collection job:

```
collection_job:
  cron: "0 20 * 1-11 1"
  class: "CheckCollectionsWorker"
  queue: critical
```

I copied and pasted `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` from the [Sidekiq-Cron GitHub page](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron):

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  schedule_file = "config/schedule.yml"

  if File.exists?(schedule_file)
    Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_hash YAML.load_file(schedule_file)
  end
end
```

The content of my `config/sidekiq.yml` file is below:

```
---
development:
  :concurrency: 5
production:
  :concurrency: 25
:queues:
  - [critical, 2]
  - default
```

I honestly have no idea about the source of this issue, since I checked many times the code inside my workers and found no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your worker. `Class CheckCollectionsWorker` should begin with lowercase: `class`